# How to have a persistent, server-side session id?

Tags: meteor

In the todos example (0.9.4), all lists are public/shared by default, unless you are logged in. How can that be modified to only show lists you've created, when you are not logged in?

I'm imagining having a persistent, server-side session id that is saved along with each list, to be used like this:

```
Meteor.publish('publicLists', function() {
  return Lists.find({sessId: Session.id(), userId: {$exists: false}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a Session on the client side and subscribe through it:

```
 //Client Side
 Session.set("listsCreatedByUnknownUserId", someId);
```

That someId can be generated whenever a new client starts using the application and replaced by the eventual userID if they were to log in, or vise versa.

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
     Meteor.startup ( function () {
       var someId = //generate unique ID for unknown client
       Session.set("listsCreatedByUnknownUserId", someId");
     }

  //Now Subscribe using that ID
  Meteor.subscribe("lists",Session.get("listsCreatedByUnknownUserId"));
 }
```

Now your lists will be subscribed off of that Session `someId`. If you user was to eventually log in then you can just transfer over all of the `Lists` that were created under the `unknownUserId` to the logged in users id through a simple `Lists.update`. I would publish lists:

```
 Meteor.publish('publicLists', function(someId) {
   return Lists.find({creatorId: someId});
 });
```

Now on any client Lists insert you simply grab that id from the Session on the insert:

```
 Lists.insert({foo:foo, creatorId: Session.get("listsCreatedByUnknownUserId")});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to disallow public usage of the application :
login is mandatory and to do that add a filter on the Router

```
var filters = {
    isLoggedIn: function() {
        console.info('filter isLoggedIn', Session.get('selectedSearch'));
        if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())) {
            this.stop(); 
            Router.go('join');
        }
    }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.isLoggedIn, {only: ['listsShow']})
```

remove insecure package and add rules on collection that will manage authorisation and alter document to add an ownerId on insertion

```
var collectionsCheck = {
"onlyConnected": function(userId, doc) {
  if (!userId) return false;

  doc.ownerId = userId;

  return true;
},

"onlyOwner": function(userId, doc) {
  if (userId == doc.ownerId) return true;

  return false;
}
};

Lists.insert({
  "insert": collectionsCheck.onlyConnected,

  "update": function() {
    return false;
  },

  "remove": collectionsCheck.onlyOwner
});

Todos.allow({
  "insert": collectionsCheck.onlyConnected,

 "update": function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    if (!userId) return false;

    if (!doc.userIds) doc.userIds = [];

    if (!_.contains(doc.userIds, userId)) doc.userIds.push(userId);

    return true;
 },

"remove": collectionsCheck.onlyOwner
});
```

And finally, add publish on subscription :

```
Meteor.publish('publicLists', function() {
    return Lists.find({userId: {$exists: false}});
});

Meteor.publish('privateLists', function() {
    if (this.userId) {
      return Lists.find({ownerId: this.userId});
    } else {
      this.ready();
    }
});

Meteor.publish('todos', function(listId) {
  check(listId, String);

  return Todos.find({listId: listId});
});
```

It should be ok, but i didn't check the code coz it's just a sample for you.